# Worksheet Function Max with condition

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a sheet that has several columns, what i am after is to display the highest number in column A if column D matches the name from the textbox.

This is the formula i got to work on the sheet, to display the last number used.

```
=MAX(INDEX((D2:D41=L11)*B2:B41,0))
```

The problem i am having, is i cant get this to convert into VBA

```
'Cells with dates also return a value, and get covered for determining largest value. Percentages will convert and return numerics.

Dim rngVal As Range
Dim rngName as range
Dim Max As Double
Dim Name As String

'Set range from which to determine largest value
Set rngVal = sheets("Payment History").Range("B2:B41")
Set rngName = sheets("Payment History").Range("D2:D41")
Name = Me.TextBox1.value

'Worksheet function MAX returns the largest value in a range
Max = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rngVal)

'Displays largest value
MsgBox Max
End Sub
```

This is the code that i have, which is displaying the max number off all values.

Comment: Do I understand correctly. The formula is working. Yet, you want to re-program that in VBA (avoiding the functions used in the formula)? May I ask why? The performance of the resulting VBA-code-solution can only be inferior.

Comment: why not simply use `Evaluate("MAX(IF(" & rngName.Address & "=L11," & rngVal.Address & "))")`?

Comment: @Ralph, Hi Ralph, yes that i correct, the reason i need it to be coded, is that i will work with a larger piece of code for another sheet, so i need it to be able to tell the user, what the last number was for the name they have selected, so they can use the next number up. Thanks

Comment: @DirkReichel, Thank you the evaluate worked perfectly. If you post the answer i will mark for you. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an easy way to "copy" formulas to vba-code you can use the `Evaluate` function. For your example, it would look like this:

```
Public Sub Test()
  Dim rngVal As String
  Dim rngName As String
  Dim xMax As Double
  Dim xName As String

  'Set range from which to determine largest value
  rngVal = Sheets("Payment History").Range("B2:B41").Address
  rngName = Sheets("Payment History").Range("D2:D41").Address
  xName = Me.TextBox1.Value

  'Worksheet function MAX returns the largest value in a range
  xMax = Evaluate("MAX(IF(" & rngName & "=" & xName & "," & rngVal & "))")

  'Displays largest value
  MsgBox xMax
End Sub
```

Hint: Do not use `Name` or `Max` because they are properties of objects and sometimes VBA gets confused if the same "name" connects to different object-types :)

Comment: Thank you for the advice, i will change that now. Its working perfectly! Thank you once again!!